# How to correctly separate style files in rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, styles

I am currently using both `rails 2` and `rails 3`

The documentation says that all styles from all pages are compiled into a single file.

For example, a new Rails application includes a default
 app/assets/javascripts/application.js file which contains the
 following lines:

```
// ...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

I'm interested in the way that rails handles this. How do I write all the styles in one file. Does it do it for each page or does it make the style in separate files? What are the differences in approach between rails 2 and rails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 3(.1 to be precise) gave us the [asset pipleline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). The asset pipeline uses application.js and application.css like you saw.

What the asset pipeline does is take all your different javascript files out there and packages them up into one big file (typically application.js).

The idea here is that you can write javascript one file per controller, like you said, and the asset pipeline later pulls everything together and serves it up as one big file. This is good for performance AND good for developers. (Small contained files are easier to reason about and maintain).

The asset pipeline also adds some conventions: javascripts live in `app/assets/javascripts` (and some other defined places too I think), one file per controller typically (but you could have more than one!), and this javascript can actually be machine generated by some language that outputs Javascript. ([Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) is an example of such a language -- Coffeescript is not Javascript, but the Coffeescript compiler outputs Javascript).

The asset pipeline brings structure to Rails apps. Typically if I'm on a project I'll have javascript live in one of three places: `app/assets/javascript` for my own app code, `lib/assets/javascript` for some common utilities I may share across different projects, and `vendor/assets/javascript` for things like jQuery or Javascript libraries from the open source community that are not mine.

Previous, with Rails 2, all your Javascript lived in `public/javascripts/`. And I mean everything: javascript files that may contain your own logic, files that might be huge (and hard for devs to reason about) because everytime you need a new jQuery callback you add it to `public/javascripts/application.js`. You could have utility modules mixed with vendor code mixed with Javascript you want to extract some day. It was, in the words of DHH, a junk drawer of stuff.

The asset pipeline gives us conventions of location, one-file-per-controller, and packaging/optimizing Javascript so that downloads are faster on the client end.

**In summary**: the Rails scaffolding command generates `app/assets/javascripts/your_controller.js.coffee`. In this file you should add Javascript related to views served by that controller. This is a best practice and a good idea.

It's worth noting that all of your Javascript code is eventually compiled by the computer into one big file, and that sometimes this abstraction leaks. (Two different javascript files binding two different events to the same Javascript id totally accidentally, for example). These leaky abstractions is why there are a lot of sharp edges to the asset pipeline, and a lot of asset pipeline questions on SO.